# How to call a method with a separate thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

let's say I have a method `doWork()`. How do I call it from a separate thread (not the main thread).

Comment: There happen to be some examples over on this recent related question: [killing an infinite loop in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489467/killing-an-infinite-loop-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832094/bring-control-from-application-to-java-frame I have a similar issue pls help me to solve this

Comment: You may also like to take a look at Reactive Java http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/ for asynchronous tasks

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Create a class that implements the `Runnable` interface. Put the code you want to run in the `run()` method - that's the method that you must write to comply to the `Runnable` interface. In your "main" thread, create a new `Thread` class, passing the constructor an instance of your `Runnable`, then call `start()` on it. `start` tells the JVM to do the magic to create a new thread, and then call your `run` method in that new thread.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int var;

    public MyRunnable(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public void run() {
        // code in the other thread, can reference "var" variable
    }
}

public class MainThreadClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(10);
        Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable)
        t.start();
    }    
}
```

Take a look at [Java's concurrency tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to get started.

If your method is going to be called frequently, then it may not be worth creating a new thread each time, as this is an expensive operation. It would probably be best to use a thread pool of some sort. Have a look at `Future`, `Callable`, `Executor` classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: what if there is a variable you would like to pass?

Comment: The `run()` method takes no parameters, so you can't pass a variable there. I'd suggest that you pass it in the constructor - I'll edit my answer to show that.

Comment: Is there a short way for calling 1 method in a different thread? I know of the `new Thread() { public void run() {myMethod();}}.start();` way, is that the shortest?

Comment: @NoelM can you explain difference between yours and MANN's answer?

Comment: MANN's answer uses an anonymous implementation of `Runnable` - mine is a class that extends `Runnable`. And because I've done that I have my own constructor which passes state into the instantiated object.

Answer (score 274):

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code goes here.
    }
});  
t1.start();
```

or

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          // code goes here.
     }
}).start();
```

or

```
new Thread(() -> {
    // code goes here.
}).start();
```

or

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myCustomMethod();
    }
});
```

or

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myCustomMethod();
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was doing. Needed to run a webservice and updating a progress bar concurrently using the observer pattern.

Comment: @Ashish: Please explain what and why has been edited?

Comment: @MANN can you explain why you use run method in Thread parameter? any better performance?

Comment: @UnKnown no, this is an inline implementation of the `Runnable` interface. You must implement the `run()` method so that `Thread` has something to run.

Comment: Do we need to explicitly terminate the thread? Isn't there a risk of creating a memory leak by not explicitly terminating the thread? Or does the thread terminate when it's done with `run()`?

Comment: In Java 8 and later we can replace `new Runnable() {...}` verbose stuff with `() -> myCustomMethod()`

Comment: it is a really nice answer. brief and clean.

Answer (score 77):

In Java 8 you can do this with one line of code.

If your method doesn't take any parameters, you can use a method reference:

```
new Thread(MyClass::doWork).start();
```

Otherwise, you can call the method in a lambda expression:

```
new Thread(() -> doWork(someParam)).start();
```

Comment: sorry to bring this back but what exactly does the `->` mean?

Comment: That is the syntax used to create a lambda expression.

Take a look at these links for more info:
[What does '->' do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20771467/1852614), and 
[The Java™ Tutorials - Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: @AaronCohn great stuff man! Do you know any alternatives to threads in Java? I come from the Python world, whre we would use `Celery task queue` for  for asynchronous stuff

Comment: Java has [higher level abstractions for dealing with Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html), but maybe you're looking for something more like [Akka](http://akka.io/)?

Comment: My method throws exception. How can I throw an exception from a thread in your first example?

Answer (score 19):

If you are using at least Java 8 you can use method `runAsync` from class [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {...});
```

If you need to return a result use `supplyAsync` instead

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

Another quicker option to call things (like DialogBoxes and MessageBoxes and creating separate threads for not-thread safe methods) would be to use the Lamba Expression

```
  new Thread(() -> {
                      "code here"
            }).start();
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little about the lifecycle of the thread created above ?

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this with RxJava 2.x you can use:

```
Completable.fromAction(this::dowork).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io().subscribe();
```

The `subscribeOn()` method specifies which scheduler to run the action on - RxJava has several predefined schedulers, including `Schedulers.io()` which has a thread pool intended for I/O operations, and `Schedulers.computation()` which is intended for CPU intensive operations.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago, I had written a simple utility class that uses JDK5 executor service and executes specific processes in the background. Since doWork() typically would have a void return value, you may want to use this utility class to execute it in the background.

See [this article](http://itmusings.com/pblog/300languages/100java/20080210-asynchronous-execution-wrapper.htm) where I had documented this utility.

Comment: Future and Callable do this kind of thing for you.

Comment: Yep they do. the idea here is to abstract the interface behind an asynchronous wrapper.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Comment: @palacsint I changed the link. Now it will work. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 you can call it through method reference by creating new thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new YourClassName::doWork);
t.start();
```

you can refer static mathod also, in that case you don't need to use new operator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).