# Methods and threads in Java

Tags: java, android

I want to create one method and call the created Thread inside that method in my Android Application, I am new to Java as I had told before.

Can anybody giive me an example of how should I create a method and call a Thread inside that method!

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to start a thread inside a method?

The simplest way is:

```
public void myMethod() {
  new Thread().start();
}
```

How you might want to do something in this thread, which can be done this way:

```
public void myMethod() {
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      // do something here...
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Of course these anonymous objects can be expanded into full-fledged ones.

Comment: This is the correct way for this to be done.  For readability, I usually create the Runnable as a private member and then its reusable wherever it needs to be called in code by: new Thread(myRunnable).start;

Comment: You are right, a member would be better if called multiple times: in this sample I went for the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a duplicate of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489543/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-separate-thread-in-java), as I've not done any work on Android. But my answer on there will explain how to run a method inside a thread.