# How to create a new thread per an existing method (like C#/NET)?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I do this in java without using the Runnable class or implementing my threaded code in a run() method?

```
public void dud()
{
   System.out.println("create me on a new thread");
}

public void main() 
{
   Thread t1 = new Thread(dud).start();
   Thread t2 = new Thread(dud).start();
}
```

Comment: You can't. There is no such construct in Java.

Comment: You can use reflection, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517028/2290235

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java 8, you can use a Lambda:

```
public void main ()
{
    // direct way
    new Thread(() -> dud()).start();
    // indirect way
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> dud());
    t.start();
}
```

Before Java 8, on Java 7, you need to use an anonymus inner class:

```
public void main ()
{
    // direct way
    new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { dud(); } }).start();
    // indirect way
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run () { dud(); } });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be able to do it implicitly if you take advantage of Java 8 features :

```
public class ThreadTest 
{
    public static void dud()
    {
        System.out.println("create me on a new thread");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Thread t1 = new Thread(()->dud()).start();

       // it might even work with a method reference :
       Thread t2 = new Thread(ThreadTest::dud).start();
    }

}
```

You are basically declaring a Runnable implicitly with a lambda expression.
Of course you'll need to either change `dud()` to be static or create an instance before invoking it.