# What does '->' do in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I was looking at some java tutorials and wasn't sure what '->' did and couldn't find anything on google about it.

Here's some code that I saw that used it:

```
myShapesCollection.stream()
.filter(e -> e.getColor() == Color.RED)
.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
```

Comment: That's the syntax of writing [lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) which is going to be included as a feature in Java 8

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is the syntax used for [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), available in Java 8.

For example, `filter` expects a `Predicate` and `e -> e.getColor() == Color.RED` is functionally equivalent to:

```
new Predicate<Shape>() {
    public boolean test(Shape s) { return s.getColor() == Color.RED; }
}
```

Comment: +1 I think the equivalent code should be `new Predicate<Shape>(){ public boolean test(Shape e){ return e.getColor() == Color.RED; } }`.