# Check how many items added in c array?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I have declared a c array of length 100.  Now, I place char's into it like this:

```
char northl2[100];

northl2[0]='1';
northl2[1]='1';
```

How can I count the number of 1's my program placed into the array?

Comment: [Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm) are your friends ;)

Comment: Are you using `c` or `c++`? These are different languages

Comment: thanx i got an idea now i will modify that question according to my need.. in future

Comment: `c`  i am using c

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/queue_program_in_c.htm is its a better idea

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. As it stands now, it is unclear at which scope your array is defined (that matters).

Comment: global defined array near name space and using this array in my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a loop like this:

```
char northl2[100] = {0};

northl2[0]='1';
northl2[1]='1';
int count_one = 0;
for (int i = 0;i<100;++i)
{
    if (northl2[i] == '1')
    {
        ++count_one;
    }
}
std::cout << count_one;
```

This prints 2 in this case, because there are 2 `1`'s. The code iterates through each element of the arrays, checks it for a value, and increments its count. The `char northl2[100] = {0};` sets by-default each element to 0. If you need a different value, use a loop:

```
char northl2[100];
int main()
{
    int count_one = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< 100;++i)
    {
         northl2[i] = 'C'; //Or whatever char other than '1'
    }
    northl2[0]='1';
    northl2[1]='1';
    for (int i = 0;i<100;++i)
    {
        if (northl2[i] == '1')
        {
            ++count_one;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to assign the 1's after the loop assigns values to all of the elements, or else, **they will be overwritten**.

Comment: but wel done array in my prog is at global

Comment: You could use a loop, I will edit my answer

Comment: @MurshadGill Answer is edited

Comment: good work this is done thankyou know at end can any body share me a link how to execute a function with thread in `c`

Comment: Er, if you found it correct, could you mark one of the answers correct by clicking the green checkmark icon on the left of the answer, so others can be helped with this answer? Also, your question is unclear @MurshadGill

Comment: yes i marked it correct . but can you please help me with link that i demanded calling function using thread in `c`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29874111/6525260 @MurshadGill

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array with a default value, e.g. `0`:

```
char northl2[100] = { 0 };
```

then after you *added* your `'1'` chars go through in a loop and increment a counter variable for each `'1'` you find.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep the number of actual elements in an array that does not have a sentinel value is to define a variable that will store the number of actual values in the array.

Take into account that if this declaration

```
char northl2[100];
```

is a block scope declaration then the array is not initialized and has indeterminate values.

If you are storing values in a character array as a string (that is the array has sentinel value `'\0'`)then you can just apply standard C function `std::strlen`.

You could define the array the following way

```
char northl2[100] = {};
```

initially initializing all elements of the array to zeroes.

In this case you could write

```
char northl2[100] = {};

northl2[0] = '1';
northl2[1] = '1';

//...

std::cout << "The number of added values to the array is " 
          << std::strlen( northl2 )
          << std::endl;
```

provided that values are added sequentially without gaps in the array.