# Why do I have to use a class that implements OnClickListener instead of declaring the callback method directly?

Tags: java, android

I just have a quick question and that is why can't I set the callback method directly in setOnClickListener() but instead I have to set a class that implements onClickListener? by saying something like setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){}) In this case I have to set an anonymous class that implements onClickListener.

Comment: because you cannot pass methods as arguements in java

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am new to java so can you be a little bit more specific to why that is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java

Comment: Hey thanks for the link it sorta help, but in the link it doesn't describe why I can't use a method as an arguments. So I still don't understand

Comment: Because java is strictly an OOP language, passing functions as parameter is not an OOP concept, hence it is not allowed in the language.

Comment: @ColinGillespie true for android java, not so much for desktop http://stackoverflow.com/a/31685857

Comment: Oh so that is the reason why you have to use a class containing the method as an argument but when you pass in a class like that how can the method get invoked? Don't class acts like a blue print and I have to create instance of that class and invoke the method of that instance?

Comment: You aren't passing in a class, you are passing an object, which is an already instantiated class. You can then access its methods same as any other object.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense but I am just passing in an object without invoking the method so how does android knows to access the method when a button let say is press?

Comment: No, every version of java allows this. The only difference is the new Java 8 allows a few new things such as lambdas. Android allows only Java 6 and Java 7

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense but I am just passing in an object without invoking the method because I when declaring an onClickListener all I am doing is setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ onClick(){system.out.print("test")}} so how does android knows to access the method when a button let say is press because all I am doing is declaring an instance of a class but not telling the class to use the method.

Comment: It knows that your object has implemented the `onClick` method so it simply calls it once it sees fit. IOW, It specified that you need to implement the onClick method since it defined that it needs a listener with that type.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand it now.