# Asynchronous File.copy in Java

Tags: java, nio, completable-future

Is there a way in Java to copy one file into another in an asynchrnous way? Something similar to [Stream.CopyToAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159084(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# is what I'm trying to find.

What I'm trying to achieve is to download a series of ~40 files from the Internet, and this is the best I've come up with for each file:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(myFiles.stream()
        .map(file -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> syncDownloadFile(file)))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::class))
    .then(ignored -> doSomethingAfterAllDownloadsAreComplete());
```

Where `syncDownloadFile` is:

```
private void syncDownloadFile(MyFile file) {
    try (InputStream is = file.mySourceUrl.openStream()) {
        long actualSize = Files.copy(is, file.myDestinationNIOPath);
        // size validation here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But that means I have some blocking calls inside of the task executors, and I'd like to avoid that so I don't block too many executors at once.

I'm not sure if the C# method internally does the same (I mean, something has to be downloading that file right?).

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing an array of CompletableFutures to allOf and not an array of MyFile? Once you call toArray it's going to block until it populates all the MyFiles

Comment: @Novaterata yeah, thanks. I changed the code a bit to remove my company's private stuff and something got messed in the process.

Comment: So you should factor out the final CompletableFuture into a variable. Then you can do whatever else you need to do and call completableFuture.get() when you need the final results. It won't block until you call get() or complete() or similar, but it will have already started on the work.

Comment: But in the process of doing that work, all my workers would have been blocked, isn't it? That's the part I'm not sure of: is it ok to put long running synchronous tasks on the workers? or for this case of copying a file to another there is a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489549/3254405

Comment: Why do you think they'd be blocked?

Comment: Because each one of them is executing `Files.copy`, which is a blocking call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsynchronousFileChannel` (AFC for short) is the right way to manage Files in Java with non-blocking IO. Unfortunately it does not provide a promises based (aka as `Task` in .net) API such as the `CopyToAsync(Stream)` of .Net.

The alternative [RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) library is built on top of the AFC and provides the `AsyncFiles` asynchronous API with different calling idioms: callbacks based, `CompletableFuture` (equivalent to .net `Task`) and also reactive streams.

For instance, copying from one file to another asynchronously can be done though:

```
Path in = Paths.get("input.txt");
Path out = Paths.get("output.txt");
AsyncFiles
      .readAllBytes(in)
      .thenCompose(bytes -> AsyncFiles.writeBytes(out, bytes))
      .thenAccept(index -> /* invoked on completion */)
```

Note that continuations are invoked by a thread from the background `AsynchronousChannelGroup`.

Thus you may solve your problem using a non-blocking HTTP client, with `ComplableFuture` based API chained with the `AsyncFiles` use. For instance, AHC is valid choice. See usage here: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client#using-continuations